# D C statehood timeline

Tags: united-states, statehood, washington-dc

Let's assume DC statehood passes Congress this summer. How soon after that could it have elections for House and Senate? How soon could those members be seated? Would they need a state constitution first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at the case of Hawaii, the most recent state to join the Union.

The Hawaii Admission Act was signed into law by President Eisenhower on March 18, 1959.  The state held elections to Congress on July 28, weeks before Statehood became effective on August 21.

Comment: I might have guessed their first Senators were appointed, but they were not, both were elected simultaneously in 1959 along with their first rep, Inouye. Just a point of clarification.